# Nuget Packages show Yellow Triangle When Reinstalling or Installing New

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I am experiencing an issue that I have never seen before.  I opened an old application (I believe it was created with VS 2015) in Visual Studio 2019, and all Nuget packages show yellow triangles.  I tried `Update-Package -reinstall`, I watch each package get reinstalled, and they still show yellow triangles.  I tried uninstalling and reinstalling using Nuget Package Manager and as soon as the package is installed it shows the yellow triangle.  I tried deleting the reference and manually adding the dll from packages folder in the solution, and I get the same thing.

I saw a post where someone suggested removing the following from the project file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
  </Target>
```

Which also didn't work.  I also tried adding packages that didn't already exist in the app, and after installing they too show with a yellow triangle.  Also, all packages show Copy Local = False.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.